# Standard Form for a Parabola

Tags: conic-sections

What is the standard form for the following problem? I already know that it is a horizontal parabola. I just can't seem to be able to change it into the standard format.

$8y² +96y-12x+240 = 0$

I have gotten it to $x = 2/3 (y + 6)² - 4$, but that's not right.

**Edit**: How do you find the focus of this parabola?

Comment: Do you know what the "correct" solution is?

Comment: Yes, all of the below should be correct solutions.

Answer (score 1):

$12x = 8(y^2+12y+36-6) = 8(y+6)^2 - 48 \to x -(-4)= \dfrac{2(y-(-6))^2}{3}$. The focus of this parabola lies on the axis of symmetry which is the line $y = -6$. We have: $F = (-4+p,-6)$, with $p = \dfrac{1}{4a} = \dfrac{1}{4\cdot \frac{2}{3}} = \dfrac{3}{8} \to F = (\frac{-29}{8},-6)$.

Comment: I think that is the same answer that he got (which he said was incorrect) ...

Comment: Thank you so much. But how would I find the focus of this parabola?

Answer (score -1):

Edit: I think the problem might be that it is not a vertical parabola.  The $y$ is squared, so it must be a sideways parabola. (Also called a horizontal parabola).

Answer (score -1):

Standard form of Vertical Parabola is $(x-x_1)=4a(y-y_1)^2$,

You can easily convert your solution to this form by some rearrangement,

$(x-(-4))=4\dfrac{1}{6}(y-(-6))^2$

Where, $(x_1,y_1)$ is the vertex of the parabola that is $(-4,-6)$

You can find the focus by shifting the vertex of the parabola by $a$ on the axis of the parabola towards its opening.

Comment: Shouldn't the vertex of the parabola be (-4,-6)?